# rewrite connection and query from mysql to mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

Been always used `MySQL` with PHP with the typical `mysql_query` or `mysql_fetch_array` but now i'm moving to `Mysqli` since it will be the future.

I'm newbie and using it for personal so i decide to ask you how to rewrite all this in rules of `Mysqli`

Let us suppose we've the following database `users(id,name,job,number)`

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(255) default '0',
  `job` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `number` varchar(255) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

INSERT INTO `users` VALUES (1, 'John', 'Plumber', '555');
INSERT INTO `users` VALUES (2, 'Iva', 'Reporter', '666');
INSERT INTO `users` VALUES (3, 'Robert', 'Writer', '777');
INSERT INTO `users` VALUES (4, 'Irin', 'Writer', '888');
```

**Now** those are of normal `Mysql` so can anyone rewrite to be with `Mysqli`

**1) Connection**

```
$DB["host"]   = "localhost";
$DB["dbName"] = "dbname";
$DB["user"]   = "dbuser";
$DB["pass"]   = "dbpass";
$link = mysql_connect($DB["host"],$DB["user"],$DB["pass"]) or die("Connection Failed");
mysql_select_db($DB["dbName"]);
```

**2) Call from the database exact entry**

```
    $sql = "select * from users where job='Plumber'";
    $reg = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $aee = mysql_fetch_array($reg);

    echo $aee[name]; // should gives name John
```

**3) Call from the database results**

```
$qry="select * from users where job='Writer'";
$result=mysql_query($qry) or die($qry);

if(mysql_num_rows($result)=='0'){

echo "No results"; // if not found any for this conditional job

}else{
while($line=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

echo $line[name]."<br>"; // should gives Robert <br> Irin

}
}
```

That would really helps me a lot and discourage me to open next new question for `insert,update,delete` as i believe this helpful for newbies like me ~ Thanks

Comment: Queries generally wont change, unless you are switching to prepared statements over direct queries. The easy way would be to use mysqli in functional mode which pretty much means changing functions from mysql_ to mysqli_.

Answer (score 1):

My answer would be not on the topic "How to rewrite from one raw API to another" but rather "How it is tend to be"

**1) Connection**

```
$params["db"]   = "dbname";
$params["user"] = "dbuser";
$params["pass"] = "dbpass";
$db = new DB($params);
```

**2) Call from the database exact entry**

```
echo $db->getOne("select name from users where job='Plumber'");
```

**3) Call from the database results**

```
$data = $db->getAll("select * from users where job='Writer'");
// assuming the following code inside of PHP template
?>
<? if(!$data): ?>
    No results
<? else: ?>
<ul>
    <? foreach($data as $line): ?>
    <li><?=$line['name']?></li>
    <? endforeach ?>
</ul>
<? endif ?>
```