# making simple query with MySQLi

Tags: php, mysqli

If i've database table with `users(name,job)` `(john,Poster)` and i made query with `MySQLi` using this code and that would works.

```
$job = "Poster";

$statement = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE `job` =  ?");
$statement->bind_param("s",$job);
$statement->execute();
$statement->bind_result($name,$job);

while ($statement->fetch()){
echo $name;
}
```

what if i made `$job = "NOTHING";` and there was no results then how can i show error such as `echo "No reuslts found";` !! the above code if `$job` was not found it will show nothing. ~ thanks

**EDIT**
this one didn't worked too :(

```
$job = "NOTHING"; // should not found and should gives error

if ($statement = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE `job` =  ?")){
$statement->bind_param("s",$job);
$statement->execute();
$statement->bind_result($name,$job);

while ($statement->fetch()){
echo $name;
}

}else{
echo "No results found dude";
}
```

Comment: Your number of rows in the result set will be zero. You can check for that and return an appropriate error.

Comment: @datasage , thanks but my question is how to check in order to write appropriate error :)

Comment: The manual on [mysqli_num_rows](http://php.net/mysqli_num_rows)

Comment: [A suggestion on how it should be](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14673088/285587). With working code.

Comment: @YourCommonSense but i'm using here prepared statement method so how can i apply it !!

Comment: @datasage i'm using here prepared statement, I've edited but still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use mysqli. It is unusable with prepared statements.
Use PDO instead.

With PDO your code would be shorter, sensible and works.

```
$statement = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE `job` =  ?");
$statement->execute(array($job));
if ($row = $statement->fetch()){
    echo $row['name'];
} else {
    echo "No results found dude";
}
```

You need to create a connection first. Something like this

```
$dsn  = 'mysql:dbname=test;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'dbuser';
$pass = 'dbpass';
$con  = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);
```

You can see details on the [manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php)

As a further step you can move to some helper library, which will make your code even shorter:

```
$name = $db->getOne("SELECT name FROM users WHERE job=?s",$job);
if ($name) {
    echo $name;
} else {
    echo "No results found dude";
}
```

But it would be wise to get yourself familiar with raw API functions first.

Comment: Thanks for help, I'm newbie and learning for just self edit of my website but i think you are right why should i move from mysql to mysqli better jump to PDO.

Comment: [who says you can't do this with mysqli prepared statements?](https://gist.github.com/4703298)

Comment: @Hiroto you can't bind variable number of placeholders nor get variable number of fields out of DB row without tons of useless dirtcode. That makes mysqli practically unusable with prepared statements.

Comment: @YourCommonSense yes you can; use `call_user_func` and pass an array.

Comment: @JackBen ironically, PDO is closer to mysql than mysqli. It has familiar fetch() function which returns an array just like mysql_fetch_array() does.

Comment: @YourCommonSense, I thought MySQLi was an improved version of original but without fetch_array(), i think i must move to PDO.